# Subquery for retrieving count

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to select all parents with the count of their children.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo b WHERE b.parent = a.name) as count 
FROM demo a 
WHERE 
    meta(a).id LIKE "xyz:%" 
    AND a.parent IS MISSING 
ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

My documents look similar to:

**xyz:1**

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "parent",
    createdAt: 1234
}
```

**xyz:2**

```
{
    id: 2,
    name: "child",
    parent: "parent",
    createdAt: 5678
}
```

I get the below error:

> Error evaluating projection. - cause: FROM in correlated subquery must have USE KEYS clause: FROM demo.
>
> Error code: 5010

**UPDATE:**
The below query seem to work:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM demo b WHERE b.parent = "parent")[0].count as count 
FROM demo a 
WHERE 
    meta(a).id LIKE "xyz:%" 
    AND a.parent IS MISSING 
ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

but if I replace `"parent"` with `a.name` it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do an ANSI JOIN followed by a GROUP BY. The query will look something like this:

```
SELECT l.name, COUNT(1)
FROM demo l JOIN demo r ON r.name = l.child
GROUP BY l.name
```

To run this query you will need an index on the r side:

```
CREATE INDEX demo_name_idx ON demo(name)
```

Be sure to test the query on actual data; there may be some wrinkles I am missing. In particular, you may want to group by l.id rather than l.name if your names are not unique.

Comment: I'm getting an error ```{
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at r",
    "query_from_user": "SELECT l.name, COUNT(1) FROM demo l JOIN demo r ON r.name = l.child GROUP BY l.name"
  }```

Comment: Niket, are you using a very old version of Couchbase? ANSI joins like this are recent functionality. Also, I changed the index, above.

Comment: My couchbase version: ```Community Edition 5.0.1 build 5003```, I guess this does not support?

Comment: You need 5.5 or later for ANSI joins.